# VueJS: getting fetch data into Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this snippet of VueJS code and a fetch inside that does a successful fetch for jokes and is intended to populate a div with it however I noticed something

```
window.onload = function () {
    var app = new Vue({
      delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        jokes: []
      }
    });

    function postdata(app){
        var initial_data = {'id': 1, 'model-name': 'Joke'}
        var self = this;
        fetch("\start-jokes\/", {
            body: JSON.stringify(initial_data),
            cache: 'no-cache', 
            credentials: 'same-origin', 
            headers: {
                'user-agent': 'Mozilla/4.0 MDN Example',
                'content-type': 'application/json'
            },
            method: 'POST',
            mode: 'cors', 
            redirect: 'follow',
            referrer: 'no-referrer',
            })
            .then(response => response.json()).then((json) => { console.log(json['jokes'])
                app.jokes.push(json['jokes'])
            })
    }

    postdata(app)
};
```

The response jokes has an Array has a dict inside with a key pair value for `key`, `text` and `name`.

[image]

but a closer look of why nothing seems to be populated I've logged the same on the console. (The prior image from the network tab in the inspect element)

[image]

Now each element in the dict has a `get` and `set` that's reactive. How can I convert it to JSON.

Note that I've tried logging on the console `app.jokes` and got back `undefined`.

Comment: Is this a question?

Comment: yes... maybe not phrased that way but I'm curious why it returns result like this (I've used the same with react and it worked) and how I can turn it into json.

Comment: Where are you logging `app.jokes`? At no point is it anything but an array. Also you probably meant to do `app.jokes.push(...json.jokes)` or `app.jokes = json.jokes` instead.

Comment: @DecadeMoon yes the decoupling seems to have done the trick.

Comment: btw: You should really look into [Axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios), which does a lot of things related to fetching data from e. g. a REST API for you and works great with Vue.

Answer (score 1):

use stranded vue methods in DOM

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      title: '',
      message: ''
    },
    mounted: function() {
      this.postdata()
    },
    methods: {
        postdata(){
            var initial_data = {'id': 1, 'model-name': 'Joke'}
            var self = this;
            fetch("\start-jokes\/", {
                body: JSON.stringify(initial_data),
                cache: 'no-cache', 
                credentials: 'same-origin', 
                headers: {
                    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/4.0 MDN Example',
                    'content-type': 'application/json'
                },
                method: 'POST',
                mode: 'cors', 
                redirect: 'follow',
                referrer: 'no-referrer',
                })
                .then(response => response.json()).then((json) => { console.log(json['jokes'])
                    this.jokes.push(json['jokes'])
                })
        }
    }
  })
```

Comment: this code https://pastebin.com/38rwhUd2 throws an error though `SyntaxError: function statement requires a name  script.js:10:18`

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/access-data-inside-mounted-vuejs